# in Vim, how to remap "\" as "," for repeat search in opposite direction

Tags: search, vim, repeat, remap

in Vim,  the function of `,` is:

> repeat latest f, t, F or T in opposite direction [count] times.

But after:

`:let mapleader = ","`

`,`can not use as repeat latest search anymore.

how to remap `\` as `,` for repeat latest search in opposite direction.

Comment: No, reusing `,` in another mapping doesn't prevent you from using it to repeat the last `fFtT` in the opposite direction. It merely adds a delay.

Comment: have you tested the `,` function before you posted the answer? btw, we have same user logo picture.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
:nnoremap \ ,
```

From `:h nnoremap`

> Map the key sequence {lhs} to {rhs} for the modes
>                           where the map command applies.  Disallow mapping of
>                           {rhs}, to avoid nested and recursive mappings.  Often
>                           used to redefine a command.

Comment: I think you swapped places with your lhs / rhs :P

Comment: @sidyll: My bad. Fixed it